# Proving that none of these elements 11, 111, 1111, 11111...can be a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, repunit-numbers

How can i prove that no number in set S 
S = {11, 111, 1111, 11111...}
Is a perfect square.

I have absolutely no idea how to tackle this problem i tried rewriting it in powers of 10 but that didn't really get me anywhere...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May i ask where this question comes from?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First notice that each element in S can be rewritten as:

$4(25m+2) +3$ where m is an integer, the next step is to realise that all squares leave a remainder of either 1 or 0 when divided by 4.

As $(2n)^2 = 4n^2$ which clearly leaves a remainder of 0 when divided by 4

And for odd squares: $(2n-1)^2 = 4n^2 -4n +1$ which clearly leaves a remainder of 1 upon division by 4.

But by writing each element of S as $4(25m+2) +3$ we see that it leaves a remainder of 3 when divided by 4, therefore it can never be a perfect square.

Comment: How did you discover that formula for 11, 111, 1111, ...?
This took me like two hours and I felt so frustrated, there is no way I could have come up with that formula on my own...

Answer (score 11):

Each number is of the form $(10^k - 1)/9$. Thus it is a perfect square if and only if $10^k - 1$ is a perfect square. But notice that for $k \ge 2$ we have $10^k - 1 \equiv 3 {\pmod 4}$, and every square is either $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I accsepted Dan's answer as I found it easier to follow.

Comment: That is perfectly fine. He also provides a proof that every square is either $0$ or $1$ modulo $4$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Notice that all numbers are $-1 \pmod 8$ except $11$.

Comment: Actually all numbers except $11$ are $7$ modulo $8$.

Comment: I just checked the first number. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In base 3, $11111 = 102^2$, and in base 7, $1111 = 26^2$.  So it's not true for bases in general.  In base 10, all such numbers are 3 modulo 4, which is never a square.